# AMPscript for Dynamic Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to setup a dynamic sender profile by only changing the Sender Name based on my records sales rep. I have 2 basic data extensions I need to use, one being my sales rep table as a reference, and the table I am sending to.

My sending table:

| SubKey | Salutation | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Dr. | John Doe | JohnDoe@email.com |
| 12346 | Dr. | Jane Doe | JaneDoe@email.com |

My sales rep reference table:

| Name | Email | Phone | SubKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sailor Jerry | sjerry@email.com | 123-456-7899 | 12345 |
| Pirate Pete | ppete@email.com | 321-654-9987 | 12346 |

The SubKey is the similar column between the two tables. I am trying to perform a Lookup and pull the Name from my Sales Rep table and paste the name in the sender profile.

This is the AMPscript i'm gaving trouble with:

```
%%[ 
var @SubKey, @SubscriberKey, @SalesRep
set @SubscriberKey = [SubscriberKey] 
set @SubKey = Lookup(“SendingTable”,”SubKey”,”SubKey”,@SubscriberKey) 
set @SalesRep = Lookup(“SalesTable”,”SubKey”,”SubKey”,@SubscriberKey) 
set @SalesRep = ProperCase(@SalesRep) 
IF Empty(@SalesRep) THEN SET @SalesRep = “Captain Kangaroo” ENDIF 
]%%

%%v=(@SalesRep)=%%
```

I plan on having the above AMPscript as a snippet, and in the sender profile to pull it by using the ContentBlockbyKey to print out the results in the sending name.

How can I make this AMPscript work to pull my SalesRep name that's associated with the record I'm sending to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to go though this article first, to understand different ways of setting up of Dynamic Sender profile.

> Dynamic Sender profile [ways to personalize the "from" and "reply to" address.](https://sfmc.in/dsp.html)

Also note you can use _SubscriberKey to pull the subscriberkey, without using Lookup from Sendable DE.

**Dynamic From-Name**

```ampscript
/* Use this snippet ID as ContentAreaID for FROM NAME in your Sender profile */
%%[ 
    var @SubscriberKey, @SalesRep_Name
    set @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
    /* set @SubKey = Lookup("SendingTable","SubKey","SubKey",@SubscriberKey)  */
    set @SalesRep_Name = Lookup("SalesTable","Name","SubKey",@SubscriberKey) 
    set @SalesRep_Name = ProperCase(@SalesRep_Name) 
    IF Empty(@SalesRep_Name) THEN 
        SET @SalesRep_Name = "Captain Kangaroo"
    ENDIF 
]%%
%%v=(@SalesRep_Name)=%%
```

**Dynamic From-EMAIL**

```ampscript
/* Use this snippet ID as ContentAreaID for FROM EMAIL in your Sender profile */
%%[ 
    var @SubscriberKey, @SalesRep_Email
    set @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") 
    /* set @SubKey = Lookup("SendingTable","SubKey","SubKey",@SubscriberKey)  */
    set @SalesRep_Email = Lookup("SalesTable","Email","SubKey",@SubscriberKey) 
    set @SalesRep_Email = ProperCase(@SalesRep_Email) 
    IF Empty(@SalesRep_Email) THEN 
        SET @SalesRep_Email = "Captain.Kangaroo@example.com"
    ENDIF 
]%%
%%v=(@SalesRep_Email)=%%
```

Comment: This appears to be working, however, it seems to only be evaluating the 1st value in the tables. Only my first record actually displays the correct SalesRep_Name, everyone else defaults to Captain Kangaroo even though the data matches and should display a SalesRep_Name

Comment: Ended up being a misplaced comma and it is all working now. Thank you for the help and the great resource!